# Store Locator with Google Maps for ExpressionEngine

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

first use of the Google Maps add-on for EE here so pardon any ignorance on my part.

I'm trying to set up a pretty standard store locator. I'm using this [Sample Store Locator Code](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/examples/search) and tweaking with my field names (see below).

{address_geocoded} is the field set to store the return from Google.

I'm getting errors along the lines of:

> ‘address_geocoded’ is not valid post variable.

Firefox and Safari generate the error right away on template load. Chrome loads the form then errors after I enter my current location and submit.

Any idears?

```
<div>
    {exp:gmap:search
        channel="retailers"
        latitude_field="address_lat"
        longitude_field="address_long"
        geocode_field="address_geocoded"
        distance_field="distance_max"
        cache_post="false"
        return="/locations/test2#demo"}

        <ul>
            <!-- <li>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title_like" id="title" value="" />
            </li> -->
            <li>
                <label for="location">Location</label>
                <input name="location" id="location" value="{if post:location}{post:location}{/if}" type="text">
                {if error:location}<p class="error">{error:location}</p>{/if}
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="location">Distance</label>
                <select name="distance_max">
                    <option value="" &#123;if="" !distance_max="" ||="" distance_max="=" ""}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">Any</option>
                    <option value="5" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 5}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">5</option>
                    <option value="10" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 10}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">10</option>
                    <option value="20" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 20}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">20</option>
                    <option value="50" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 50}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">50</option>
                    <option value="100" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 100}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">100</option>
                </select>
            </li>

            <li>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </li>
        </ul>       

    {/exp:gmap:search}
</div>

<div>

    {exp:gmap:init id="map" class="gmap" style="width:100%;height:200px"}

    {exp:gmap:results order_by="distance" sort="asc" parse="inward"}

        {if has_searched}
            <ul>
            {results}
                <li>{title} - {distance}</li>
            {/results}
            </ul>

            {results}                   
                {exp:gmap:marker id="map" latitude="{address_lat}" longitude="{address_long}"}
            {/results}

        {if:else}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="retailers" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|categories|category_fields|pagination" parse="inward"}

                {location_gmap id="map"}

            {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/if}

        {if absolute_count == 1}
        <p><em>Hint: Try searching for 'Hoosier National Forest' at a distance of 20 miles.</em></p>
        {/if}

        {if no_results}

            <p>No results found</p>

            {exp:channel:entries channel="retailers" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|categories|category_fields|pagination" parse="inward"}

                {location_gmap id="map"}

            {/exp:channel:entries}

        {/if}

    {/exp:gmap:results}

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as I think you must you must use `geocode_field`  param value as a name for your HTML input.

so in your code you change the `geocode_field` from location to address_geocoded but you keep the HTML field name as it "location".

so the code try to find $_post['address_geocoded'] and it not find it.

this is a guess , because I don't work on Google Maps add-on for EE before, but I almost sure if you change the HTML input name to address_geocoded this will solve the problem.

**Update:**

the address field is required but you can use more fields that will create an address string that will be geocoded as mention here :

https://www.objectivehtml.com/google-maps/documentation/tag/search#geocode_field

so if you want to use another field like "address_geocoded" you must change your code to:

```
    {exp:gmap:search
    channel="retailers"
    latitude_field="address_lat"
    longitude_field="address_long"
    geocode_field="address|address_geocoded"
    distance_field="distance_max"
    cache_post="false"
    return="/locations/test2#demo"}
```

notice **geocode_field="address|address_geocoded"** and you must add a new HTML field with address_geocoded name.

I hope this will do the trick

Regard's.

Comment: Tried that, no dice. Same error but with "address" rather than address_geocoded.

Comment: just for check, if you use the same document code did you have the same error , if yes can you give me a test url so I can see what happened?

Comment: check the updates

Comment: No dice. I read in the docs that a field with the name of "location" is expected - which I had a question about because that's a reserved field name in EE so I can't name a channel field 'location')

At any rate I added the multiple fields with the change d HTML name and same error as before.

Comment: I don't know what else you can do , anyway just to make sure you tell me you have the same error but with "address" what you do when you get this error , did you change the param value to "address" or you change the HTML input name to "address_geocoded"??

Comment: and another thing when you change HTML input name to "address_geocoded" you must change `{post:location}` to `{post:address_geocoded}`

Comment: Yes - I changed the param value, the HTML field name, and the {post:location} variable and continue to get the same error.

Comment: can you post the code after you changed it

Answer (score 0):

I think my issue was mainly the browser caching the post variables, so when I would make a code change and reload the page the same error would generate.  I got past the post variable related errors with this code:

```
 <div>
    {exp:gmap:search
        channel="retailers"
        latitude_field="address_lat"
        longitude_field="address_long"
        geocode_field="address_map|address_geocoded"
        distance_field="distance_max"
        cache_post="false"
        return="/locations/test2#demo"}

        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="address_geocoded">Location</label>
                <input name="address_geocoded" id="address_geocoded" value="{if post:address_geocoded}{post:address_geocoded}{/if}" type="text">
                {if error:address_geocoded}<p class="error">{error:address_geocoded}</p>{/if}
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="distance_max">Distance</label>
                <select name="distance_max">
                    <option value="" &#123;if="" !distance_max="" ||="" distance_max="=" ""}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">Any</option>
                    <option value="5" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 5}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">5</option>
                    <option value="10" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 10}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">10</option>
                    <option value="20" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 20}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">20</option>
                    <option value="50" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 50}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">50</option>
                    <option value="100" &#123;if="" distance_max="=" 100}selected="selected" &#123;="" if}="">100</option>
                </select>
            </li>

            <li>
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </li>
        </ul>       

    {/exp:gmap:search}
</div>

<div>

    {exp:gmap:init id="map" class="gmap" style="width:100%;height:200px"}

    {exp:gmap:results order_by="distance" sort="asc" parse="inward"}

        {if has_searched}
            <ul>
            {results}
                <li>{title} - {distance}</li>
            {/results}
            </ul>

            {results}                   
                {exp:gmap:marker id="map" latitude="{address_lat}" longitude="{address_long}"}
            {/results}

        {if:else}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="retailers" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|categories|category_fields|pagination" parse="inward"}

                {address_map id="map"}

            {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/if}

        {if absolute_count == 1}
        <p><em>Hint: Try searching for 'Hoosier National Forest' at a distance of 20 miles.</em></p>
        {/if}

        {if no_results}

            <p>No results found</p>

            {exp:channel:entries channel="retailers" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|categories|category_fields|pagination" parse="inward"}

                {address_map id="map"}

            {/exp:channel:entries}

        {/if}

    {/exp:gmap:results}

</div>
```

Now onto other issues - like the search not returning results...;)